# How can I log information without using alert in userscripts

Tags: javascript, userscripts

i have an userscript which traces all the dynamically created tags in javascript of a webpage. the problem here is presently i am using alert box to dispaly the output. The problem with alert() is that it can be very obtrusive. For every alert, you need to click the OK button to proceed which wastes your time. so i want an alternative method like log files other than alert box. how can i do this.

i am restricted to use console.log

Comment: for console.log we have to go to inspectelement->console in which the user might not be comfortable. MY application should display the output when the script is run without the user going for console to view the output. sorry i forgot to mention this

Comment: Do you want to log information for you (developer/helpdesk) only, or does a normal user has to be able to see it?

Comment: Normal user should be able to see it.

Comment: @user1275375 - Then just add the output to the page's HTML. At this point, I'm not sure about what you have in mind :-?

Comment: is it possible to add code into website using userscript

Comment: @user1275375 offcourse. Check out Firefox Greasemonkey, Opera userscripts, or any browsers' console where you can enter javascript on the fly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use some kind of console element statically placed on your page which can be hidden if necessary. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MhhRp/).

HTML:

```
<div id="console">
  <div class="header">
     Console
     <span class="expand" onclick="toggleConsole();">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#console {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}
#console .header {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}
#console .header .expand {
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#console .content {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #F9F9F0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function log(text) {
    var consoleContent = document.getElementById('console')
        .getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
    var line = document.createElement('div');
    line.className = 'consoleLine';
    line.innerHTML = text;
    consoleContent.appendChild(line);
}

function toggleConsole() {
    var content = document.getElementById('console')
        .getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
    if (content.style.display === "none") {
        content.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('console')
            .getElementsByClassName('expand')[0].innerHTML = "-";
    } else {
        content.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('console')
            .getElementsByClassName('expand')[0].innerHTML = "+";
    }
}

document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('console')
        .getElementsByClassName('expand')[0].onclick = toggleConsole;
};
```

Use `log("some text");` to output to your console !

Comment: That approach is the right idea. [Put the relevant code here, in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/148310), not just at some 3rd-party site, and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Install firefox add-on to your Mozilla(if you are using) and you the follwing code:

```
console.log("test"+your_variable);
```

So above code will display all logs in console.If IE press F12 and check console.

Comment: Note that with console.log you can pass multiple parameters. So instead of `console.log("My object is: " + myObj)` you can say `console.log("My object is: ", myObj)` which will let you expand the object and see its properties

Comment: Yes we can. I just explained to get an idea.Anyway thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

If a normal user should be able to see it, using the console is not a very user-friendly way.

Define a space on your webpage (a `<div>` might be handy) where you want the information to be, and just add the messages to that space using javascript (or jQuery) to modify the DOM:

HTML:

```
<div id='logmessages'>Log messages:</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function log(yourMsg) {
document.getElementByID('logmessages').innerHTML() += yourMsg;
}
```

It might be friendly to allow the user to show/hide the div with a button or another way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fixed div either at the top, bottom or corner of your page with set width/height and overflow auto, then insert the log entries in it.